# Is the work done in carrying a positive charge in a circuit back to the original place $=0$

Tags: electric-circuits, potential, batteries

Is the work done in carrying a positive charge in a circuit back to the original place $=0$ ? my intuition says so, after all electromagnetic forces are conservative and the work done done against a conservative force is always equal to 0 when you return it back to the original position. But my book says it is equal to the emf value in a closed circuit.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are talking about positive charge in a circuit.

Positive charge leaving the positive terminal and moving through the circuit to the negative terminal loses electrical potential energy either in the form of resistive heating, and/or as energy stored in the electric or magnetic field of capacitance or inductance. The battery then supplies it (by the conversion of chemical potential energy) with an equal amount of electrical potential energy moving the charge from the negative to positive terminal within the battery (its original starting point).

So the loss of electrical potential energy of the charge in the circuit equals the gain in electrical potential energy from the battery, for total change of zero.

This is the basis of Kirchhoff's voltage law.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh yes i had misread my textbook, it said emf was "the energy supplied by the source in a circuit". Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Say your circuit is simply the battery and the wire, the wire has some resistance inherently.

The positive charge is initially just near the plus terminal.

The positive moves out of the plus side goes through the circuit and comes to the minus side of the battery. In doing so, the batter has expended an energy equal to the potential difference across the wire, which is basically the emf.

Now, you said " bring the charge to the original place" . This means we have to travel through the battery and reach the positive terminal from the negative terminal.

You need to personally pull the charge against the battery to do this.

The work done by you thus is against the battery.

Now, if you add these two works, one done by the battery and one done by you against the battery, the total work will be zero.

( The work you do is actually charging up the battery)

Comment: Keep in mind that it is the negative charges that move through a conductor.